# How to prove irreducibility of $P(x)=x^4-2x^3-2x^2+2x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have polynomial $P(x)=x^4-2x^3-2x^2+2x-1$ and I have strong suspicions it's irreducible. Any ideas how to prove that?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint : use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion after a shift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Q$, because it is already irreducible modulo $3$, so over $\Bbb F_3$, which is easy to see.

Alternatively, you can use Eisenstein with a shift $x\mapsto x+1$, or just see it directly, like in this post: [Show that polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836823/show-that-polynomial-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq?rq=1)